# Invariant subspace proof involving determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, invariant-subspace

This is a linear algebra textbook question:

If $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace, we denote by $T: W \rightarrow W$ be the map defined by $T_W (v) = T(v)$.

(a) Let $V$ be finite-dimensional and $W$ a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. Show that there exists a polynomial $g(t)$ such
that
$$\det(T − tI_V ) = g(t) \det(T_W − tI_W ).$$

To begin this, I'm thinking these determinants would yield the characteristic polynomial of $T$ in subspace $V$ and $T$ in subspace $W$. Then based on that polynomial we should be able to determine $g(t)$. However, I'm not sure at all what $\det(T − tI_V )$ or $\det(T_W − tI_W )$ should look like. Could someone please assist in continuing this thought process and explain what they should look like to continue this proof?

Comment: What's your definition of the determinant? If you know the determinant of a block-triangular matrix depends only only the diagonal blocks, then you can simply extend a basis of $W$ to $V$, and then $T$ is expressible in block-triangular form, then the $g(t)$ will be the characteristic polynomial of the other diagonal block not associated to $W$.

Comment: @runway44 Not familiar with the determinant of a block-triangular matrix, but will happily research it. How can I then obtain the the () will be the characteristic polynomial of the other diagonal block not associated to ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're defining determinants by Leibniz formula / expansion-by-minors?

Comment: I'm guessing you're defining determinants by Leibniz formula / expansion-by-minors? You show the off-diagonal block doesn't affect the determinant (by induction, say). Then you can show the determinant factors as a product of the determinant of the two diagonal blocks. Alternatively, there might be a "linear-algebra-done-right" proof that doesn't use matrices and shows the one char poly divides the other. You should also say what textbook and problem this is so it can be clearer what the text has prepared the reader with and expects of them.